# Use a PHP variable inside a jquery click()?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#link').click(function(){
            var user_login = <?php $base_url; ?>;
            window.location = user_login + '/login';
        });

    });
```

note that `$base_url` is global variable. This works in FF but not on Chrome and IE. Thanks.

Comment: Right click on the webpage then Click `View Source` and see how it is rendered in Chrome and IE.

Comment: In which kind of file is this code: in a *.php page I suppose ?

Comment: @RomainBruckert, in a separate *.js file.

Comment: Try also var login = "<?php echo $base_url; ?>"; Login URL would be a string, you need to enclose it within quotes.

Comment: How can PHP work in a JS file... ? Sorry, did i miss something ? :p

Comment: You can't execute PHP in an external javascript file because that file is never executed via PHP. You would need to embed the code in the php page, or pass as a querystring variable to the script tag.

Comment: just put your script in the php file. External js file don't process the php.

Comment: @RomainBruckert, oh shoot, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @CHi RiLo No problemo. Nonetheless, even is you write this in a PHP page, all the answers bellow are valid: use quote and ECHO your variable ! ;)

Comment: `This works in FF but not on Chrome and IE. Thanks.` Yes, master...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Run this script in a PHP file**, not in a .js file, and don't forget tho ECHO your variable and add quotes (in javascript), as said in other answers !

Comment: Well thought out answer. Good job.

Comment: How is this downvoted, beeing accepted, solving the problem, straightforward and true ?? Sorry, don't get it

Comment: you basically just said "look at all the other answers here - that's your answer" - I wouldn't call that an acceptable answer

Comment: I basically said that any of the answers would work.. IF ONLY not in a JS file... which was the main problem here.

Comment: It's OK, I'll move on. I'd just say to be careful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers

Answer (score 5):

You need to add quotes around the php tags to designate that the value of $base_url is a string:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#link').click(function(){
        var user_login = "<?php echo $base_url; ?>";
        window.location = user_login + '/login';
    });

});
```

That way, when the browser gets this block, it will look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#link').click(function(){
        var user_login = "http://www.example.com"; // after php is executed
        window.location = user_login + '/login';
    });

});
```

Comment: it just treats the thing between the quotes as string.

Comment: should be var login = <?php '\''.$base_url.'\''; ?>;

Comment: @CHiRiLo - I mentioned above as a comment to your post about processing PHP in an external js file. It won't work, because php isn't executed on that file. That file is only included after the php page is sent to the browser. The server doesn't know to use php to parse the .js file, so the variable is never replaced with the value. - Since this is a server issue, I don't see how this works in FF and not in others - unless we're missing some information.

Comment: @Akash - no that's not correct. What we're looking for here is a value of `$base_url` that is used as a string in the javascript. The quotes are not necessary in the PHP block, but are necessary in the javascript block.

Answer (score 3):

You need to echo the variable, not just simply have it in a code block. And for safety, to prevent introducing JS syntax errors, you should json-encode the value:

```
        var login = <?php echo json_encode($base_url); ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

See below, note the quotes around the PHP echo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#link').click(function(){
        var login = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>';
        window.location = user_login + '/login';
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose its a PHP file, you need to surround your variable contents by quotes to javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#link').click(function(){
            var login = <?php '\''.$base_url.'\''; ?>;
            window.location = user_login + '/login';
        });

    });
```